# QueryException (23000) SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint v1452

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am sucked by this error since this week could any one help me please !
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`practice2`.`posts`, CONSTRAINT `posts_category_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)) (SQL: insert into `posts` (`author_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2, 2017-11-13 05:48:53, 2017-11-13 05:48:53))

**my codes are:**
**Blog controller :**

```
 public function store(Requests\PostRequest $request)
        {
            $request->user()->posts()->create($request->all());
            redirect('/backend/blog')->with('message', 'Your post was created successfully!');
        }

**migration:** 

 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict');
            $table->string('tittle');
            $table->string('slug')->unique;
            $table->text('excerpt');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->string('image')-> nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**alter_post_migration :**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('restrict');
            //
        });
    }
```

**create post form:**

```
<div class="box-body ">
                    {!! Form::model($post, [
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'route' => 'back.store'
                    ]) !!}

                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('tittle') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('tittle') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('tittle', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                        @if($errors->has('tittle'))
                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('tittle') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('slug') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('slug') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('slug', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                        @if($errors->has('slug'))
                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('slug') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {!! Form::label('excerpt') !!}
                        {!! Form::textarea('excerpt', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('body') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('body') !!}
                        {!! Form::textarea('body', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                        @if($errors->has('body'))
                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('body') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('published_at') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('published_at', 'Publish Date') !!}
                        {!! Form::text('published_at', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Y-m-d H:i:s']) !!}

                        @if($errors->has('published_at'))
                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('published_at') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('category_id') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
                        {!! Form::label('category_id', 'Category') !!}
                        {!! Form::select('category_id', App\Category::pluck('tittle', 'id'), null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Choose category']) !!}

                        @if($errors->has('category_id'))
                            <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('category_id') }}</span>
                        @endif
                    </div>

                    <hr>

                    {!! Form::submit('Create new post', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you are trying to insert a `posts` record which doesn't have a valid `category_id`. It is likely defaulting the `category_id` to null, and there is no null `category_id` row. Suggest either add a default category (e.g. 0) and set uncategorized posts to this, or change the `posts.category_id` to allow for nulls.

Comment: I have altered the table later and there is category_id field in posts table

Answer (score 1):

The error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (practice2.posts, CONSTRAINT
>   posts_category_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES
>   categories (id))

comes when two table share a relationship of `foreign key` and you are trying to add some data in child table and its associated record does not exist in the parent table. So check the data accordingly and try again.